# How to consider independent samples in a mixed-design experiment?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, experiment-design, independence, median

I collected data from an experiment with a mixed-design, specifically a 2x3x4 mixed-design, where the factors are populations (2 levels), conditions for the first population (3 levels), and conditions for the second population (4 levels). In each condition, there are 5 repeated measures for 13 collected items. Not all participants performed the test in every condition. I would like to analyze differences both within and between subjects and also between populations in the respective conditions. Leaving aside the checks for normality and homoscedasticity, how to consider independent samples in this context to perform some statistical test without violating basic assumptions? Is considering the medians of the 5 measures and performing tests on those a viable choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this type of design, involving repeated measures, because of the interplay between between-subjects factors (the two populations) and within-subjects factors (the differing conditions for each population), the analysis can be quite complex.

One approach would be to start with a Mixed ANOVA (also known as Split Plot ANOVA). This would be the simplest approach for your design. This is capable of dealing with both within-subjects (repeated measures) and between-subjects issues. This test allows you to compare differences among subjects (between conditions) and between subjects (between two populations).

It appears that you have missing data because not all participants performed the test in all conditions. Mixed ANOVA can accommodate some missing data, especially if the missing data is random. However, if the missingness is systematic, your results may be skewed. You might consider using Multiple Imputation in that case.

For the repeated measures (5 repeated measures for 13 items), you can use these as within-subject factors in the ANOVA. However, if you're concerned about the independence of observations (which you should be), or if there's significant variability in the repeated measures, you might consider reducing these repeated measures to a single value per condition per participant, as you suggested. However, the drawback with this is that you lose statistical power and are not making the most of your data.

Instead I would suggest, a Linear Mixed Effects Model, with random intercepts for subjectID. In R this would be something like:

```
library(lme4)

# Fit the mixed effects model
# - response: The dependent variable
# - population: Between-subject factor (2 levels)
# - condition1: Within-subject factor for the first population (3 levels)
# - condition2: Within-subject factor for the second population (4 levels)
# - subjectID: Random effect for subjects

model <- lmer(response ~ population * condition1 * condition2 + (1 | subjectID), data = mydata)
```

**Within-Subject Effects:** Look at the fixed effect coefficients for `condition1` and `condition2`. This tells you how the response variable changes within subjects as the conditions change.

**Between-Subject Effects:** Examine the coefficients for the `population` variable. This will show you the differences between the two populations.

**Interaction Effects:** Interaction terms (eg, `population:condition1` and `population:condition2)` can reveal whether the effect of the conditions on the response variable differs between populations. The three-way interaction between `population`, `condition1`, and `condition2` would indicate that the effect of the interaction between the two conditions (`condition1` and `condition2`) on the response variable differs depending on the population. For example, if `condition1` and `condition2` interact differently with the response variable in different populations, this implies a complex interplay between all three factors. It suggests that the relationship between the conditions and the response is not uniform across populations; instead, it is modified by the population group.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try the Linear Mixed Effects Model you suggested. For what concerns ANOVA, I'll avoid it because of the violation of normality and homoscedasticity assumptions, and go with a non-parametric like Friedman test.

Comment: I am returning back to this @Robert Long. I am trying to perform a Linear Mixed Effects Model on my dataset but I am stuck with some issues. One is the assumptions of this model. I found that the residuals should be normally distributed, and that is not my case. Another thing is the implementation. I have one column (namely, "Condition") for all the seven levels, and I don't know how to create two columns without bumping into NaN values or empty cells for each row. 
So I used the formula: response ~ Population * Condition + (1 | Participant). Does it make any sense?

Comment: @AndreaGulli please post a new question about this. You can ping me again here after you post it and then I will be happy to take a look when I have time. Please don't ping me on in the comments of the new post - the system doesn't work like that and I won't get a notification.

Comment: posted! Thank you very much!